# Issue in update records in c#

Tags: c#

Here is searchupdate_Click code:

```
 protected void searchupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("sp_searchupdate", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textstudentid.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        txttamil.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tamil"].ToString();
        txtenglish.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["English"].ToString();
        txtmaths.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Maths"].ToString();
        txtscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Science"].ToString();
        txtsocialscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]"SocialScience"].ToString();
    }
 }
```

When I enter student id and search, it showed student marks in `textboxes`.

After that I want to edit and update.

For that I have added above code, and here its `stored procedure`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_searchupdate
(
    @id int,
    @Tamil varchar(50),
    @English varchar(50),
    @Maths varchar(50),
    @Science varchar(50),
    @SocialScience varchar(50)
)

AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studentresult WHERE id_student='@id') 
begin
SELECT id_student FROM studentresult WHERE id_student='@id'
END
```

When I edit marks, and hit update button, it shows error.

Here is my output [**screenshot**](http://s29.postimg.org/elqolzziv/untitled.jpg)

May I know, what my mistake in the code, I'm new to .net.

Can anyone help me?

update:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_searchupdate
(
    @id int,
@Tamil Varchar (100),
@English varchar (50),
@Maths Varchar (50),
@Science Varchar (50),
@SocialScience Varchar (50) 
)

AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studentresult WHERE id_student=@id) 
BEGIN
UPDATE studentresult SET Tamil = @Tamil,English = @English, Maths = @Maths,Science = @Science,SocialScience = @SocialScience WHERE id = @id
END
```

Comment: Which Exception and where is your update code??

Comment: I don't see update code....

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s: i can't understand...

Comment: @nic: may i know, what you need?

Comment: The **name** of your stored procedure **SHOULD NOT** start with  `sp_` since this is a Microsoft-reserved prefix, and it causes extra lookups to happen that cost time every time you execute your procedure

Comment: but before that i used sp for insert,update,delete and it works fine

Comment: can you post the exception details? screenshots don't work in hell lot of places

Comment: @Rani Where is your update statement ? I only can see you are selecting the record in SQL but not Updating. Here is the link where your update statement should be .. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: i updated my post, and here is the error screenshot http://s4.postimg.org/f7s284e25/untitled.jpg

Comment: @Rani you expect people to read that size of image ??? It's so small until almost cannot see it.. Then we zoom in will be all blur...

Answer (score 0):

First at all you must understand how your current code work...
Let's say when you click `searchupdate` this should do what kind of job?

 Now base on your code now is actually setting the `TextBox` to the `Database` value you retrieve.

Is this what you expect ? Answer is **NO** 
I have separated to 2 button due to your function 1 is for search and another 1 is for update....

```
// This is First Button
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // What does theis code here do ??
    SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("PROCEDURE_SELECT", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtstudentid.Text.Trim());
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);

        // SEt value to TextBox & make sure your value below is not Null else it will throw you null exception due to you use .ToString()
        txttamil.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Tamil"].ToString();
        txtenglish.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["English"].ToString();
        txtmaths.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Maths"].ToString();
        txtscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Science"].ToString();
        txtsocialscience.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SocialScience"].ToString();
    }    
}

// This is second Button
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PROCEDURE_UPDATE", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Add your Parameter
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtstudentid.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tamil", txttamil.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@english", txtenglish.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@math", txtmaths.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@science", txtscience.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@socialScience", txtsocialscience.Text.Trim());


            con.Open();

            // Execute your Query
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Clear All The Data in Current TextBOx and press search again with the ID
            txttamil.Text = string.Empty;
            txtenglish.Text = string.Empty;
            txtmaths.Text = string.Empty;
            txtscience.Text = string.Empty;
            txtsocialscience.Text = string.Empty;

            Response.Write("You have updated the value... Try to Search again...");
        }

        // UPDATE Query as per below
        // IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM studentresult WHERE id_student='@id') 
        // BEGIN
        //     UPDATE TABLE SET tamil = @tamil and so on... WHERE id = @id
        // END
        // ELSE
        // BEGIN
        //     INSERT DATA HERE
        // END
    }
}
```

SQL Proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_Upd_Student
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @id VARCHAR(100),
    @tamil VARCHAR(100),
    @english VARCHAR(100),
    @maths VARCHAR(100),
    @science VARCHAR(100),
    @socialscience VARCHAR(100)     
AS
BEGIN
    -- CHECK IF THE TABLE CONTAIN THE SAME ID
    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE WHERE id = @id) > 0 
    BEGIN
        -- I DO UPDATE TO THE TABLE
        UPDATE TABLE
        SET Column = VALUE
        WHERE id = @id
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- IF A NEW ID ? THEN I DO INSERT, IF YOUR ID IS IDENTITY THEN YOU CAN SKIP IT NO NEED TO INSERT
        INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN)
        VALUE
        (PARAM)
    END
END
```

The store procedure above is for `Update & Insert`... Your `Select proc` can remain due to is different procedure. If you want to combine you add one more parameter called `@Action`

Comment: i want to use if exists (select * ...) this is what told me my boss.. but you told me,, update query.

Comment: and             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtstudentid.Text.Trim());  in this line  txtstudentid doesnot exist in the current context.

Comment: may i know.. can you show me,storedprocedure query with elaborate..?. thanks

Comment: i updated marks, it shows "updated value".. but when i check in studentresult table.. it doesn't updated.. thanks

Comment: my query updated in my post at the bottom..can you please check? thanks

Comment: I changed id_student=@id.. it works fine.. but if i enter id like 100.. but id number 100 have not marks stored in table means.. what to do?..

Comment: Not mean that... i think i need to add some condition right?

Comment: Not mean that,i think i need to add condition right?

Comment: Ok.. i followed your above query,. But it shows error like this incorrect syntex near '>´ and column..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96013/discussion-between-rani-and-nic).

Comment: what i need is that: if i enter id and search,which is not have marks.then i need to insert and click update.. thanks

Comment: @Rani you don't need to follow my query you just use back your origin then put an else there and do insert statement... That's all ...

Answer (score 0):

Since your SP expects parameters.

[image]

You have to pass the expected parameters to the stored procedure from C#. Like below,

***btnSearch_Click***

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tamil", "");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@English", "");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maths", "");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Science", "");
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocialScience", "");
```

***btnUpdate_Click***

```
// Add your Parameter
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtstudentid.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tamil", txttamil.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@english", txtenglish.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@math", txtmaths.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@science", txtscience.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@socialScience", txtsocialscience.Text);
```

Comment: may i know, what my stored procedure will be?